# Access Denied while attempting to join AD domain using Centos 7

Tags: active-directory, centos7

I've tried for days to get [these instructions](http://www.hexblot.com/blog/centos-7-active-directory-and-samba) to work, but despite everything, I cannot join my domain.

When I execute `realm discover`, I am able to see my domain just fine:

```
[root@centos5 ~]# realm discover home.domain.com
home.domain.com
  type: kerberos
  realm-name: HOME.domain.COM
  domain-name: home.domain.com
  configured: no
  server-software: active-directory
  client-software: sssd
  required-package: oddjob
  required-package: oddjob-mkhomedir
  required-package: sssd
  required-package: adcli
  required-package: samba-common
[root@centos5 ~]#
```

but when I try to join it, after being asked for my password, I get the following:

```
[root@centos5 ~]# realm join -U user home.domain.com
Password for user:
See: journalctl REALMD_OPERATION=r158905.22733
realm: Couldn't join realm: Joining the domain home.domain.com failed
[root@centos5 ~]#
```

journalctl shows the following:

```
Mar 05 10:37:47 centos5.home.domain.com dbus[731]: [system] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.realmd' (using servicehelper)
Mar 05 10:37:47 centos5.home.domain.com dbus-daemon[731]: dbus[731]: [system] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.realmd' (using servicehelper)
Mar 05 10:37:47 centos5.home.domain.com realmd[22736]: Loaded settings from: /usr/lib64/realmd/realmd-defaults.conf /usr/lib64/realmd/realmd-distro.conf
Mar 05 10:37:47 centos5.home.domain.com realmd[22736]: holding daemon: startup
Mar 05 10:37:47 centos5.home.domain.com realmd[22736]: starting service
Mar 05 10:37:47 centos5.home.domain.com realmd[22736]: connected to bus
Mar 05 10:37:47 centos5.home.domain.com realmd[22736]: released daemon: startup
Mar 05 10:37:47 centos5.home.domain.com dbus[731]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.realmd'
Mar 05 10:37:47 centos5.home.domain.com dbus-daemon[731]: dbus[731]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.realmd'
Mar 05 10:37:47 centos5.home.domain.com realmd[22736]: claimed name on bus: org.freedesktop.realmd
Mar 05 10:37:47 centos5.home.domain.com realmd[22736]: client using service: :1.112
Mar 05 10:37:47 centos5.home.domain.com realmd[22736]: holding daemon: :1.112
Mar 05 10:37:47 centos5.home.domain.com realmd[22736]: Using 'r158905.22733' operation for method 'Discover' invocation on 'org.freedesktop.realmd.Provider' interface
Mar 05 10:37:47 centos5.home.domain.com realmd[22736]: Registered cancellable for operation 'r158905.22733'
Mar 05 10:37:47 centos5.home.domain.com realmd[22736]:  * Resolving: _ldap._tcp.home.domain.com
Mar 05 10:37:47 centos5.home.domain.com realmd[22736]:  * Resolving: _ldap._tcp.home.domain.com
Mar 05 10:37:47 centos5.home.domain.com realmd[22736]:  * Performing LDAP DSE lookup on: 192.168.2.6
Mar 05 10:37:47 centos5.home.domain.com realmd[22736]:  * Performing LDAP DSE lookup on: 192.168.2.6
Mar 05 10:37:47 centos5.home.domain.com realmd[22736]: Searching  for (objectClass=*)
Mar 05 10:37:47 centos5.home.domain.com realmd[22736]: Got defaultNamingContext: DC=home,DC=domain,DC=com
Mar 05 10:37:47 centos5.home.domain.com realmd[22736]: Sending TCP Netlogon request
Mar 05 10:37:47 centos5.home.domain.com realmd[22736]: Received TCP Netlogon response
Mar 05 10:37:47 centos5.home.domain.com realmd[22736]:  * Successfully discovered: home.domain.com
Mar 05 10:37:47 centos5.home.domain.com realmd[22736]:  * Successfully discovered: home.domain.com
Mar 05 10:37:49 centos5.home.domain.com realmd[22736]: Using 'r158905.22733' operation for method 'Join' invocation on 'org.freedesktop.realmd.KerberosMembership' interface
Mar 05 10:37:49 centos5.home.domain.com realmd[22736]: Registered cancellable for operation 'r158905.22733'
Mar 05 10:37:49 centos5.home.domain.com realmd[22736]: holding daemon: current-invocation
Mar 05 10:37:49 centos5.home.domain.com realmd[22736]:  * Required files: /usr/sbin/oddjobd, /usr/libexec/oddjob/mkhomedir, /usr/sbin/sssd, /usr/bin/net
Mar 05 10:37:49 centos5.home.domain.com realmd[22736]:  * Required files: /usr/sbin/oddjobd, /usr/libexec/oddjob/mkhomedir, /usr/sbin/sssd, /usr/bin/net
Mar 05 10:37:49 centos5.home.domain.com realmd[22736]:  * LANG=C LOGNAME=root /usr/bin/net -s /var/cache/realmd/realmd-smb-conf.7OYXDY -U user ads join home.domain.com
Mar 05 10:37:49 centos5.home.domain.com realmd[22736]:  * LANG=C LOGNAME=root /usr/bin/net -s /var/cache/realmd/realmd-smb-conf.7OYXDY -U user ads join home.domain.com
Mar 05 10:37:49 centos5.home.domain.com realmd[22736]: process started: 22742
Mar 05 10:37:49 centos5.home.domain.com realmd[22736]: Could not initialise message context. Try running as root
Mar 05 10:37:49 centos5.home.domain.com realmd[22736]: Could not initialise message context. Try running as root
Mar 05 10:37:49 centos5.home.domain.com realmd[22736]: Failed to join domain: Access is denied
Mar 05 10:37:49 centos5.home.domain.com realmd[22736]: Failed to join domain: Access is denied
Mar 05 10:37:49 centos5.home.domain.com realmd[22736]: process exited: 22742
Mar 05 10:37:49 centos5.home.domain.com realmd[22736]:  ! Joining the domain home.domain.com failed
Mar 05 10:37:49 centos5.home.domain.com realmd[22736]:  ! Joining the domain home.domain.com failed
Mar 05 10:37:49 centos5.home.domain.com realmd[22736]: released daemon: current-invocation
Mar 05 10:37:49 centos5.home.domain.com realmd[22736]: client gone away: :1.112
Mar 05 10:37:49 centos5.home.domain.com realmd[22736]: released daemon: :1.112
```

What confuses me about the log message is that it says **Could not initialise message context. Try running as root**. I don't know if this has any significance, but I am most definitely running as root.

Another thing that is confusing is the **Access Denied** message. I'm 100% certain that I have the correct user and password when trying to join the domain.

Just for completeness, I attempted to follow the same instructions that work fine on my Centos 6 virtual machines, and I also get an error when I run `authconfig`:

```
[root@centos5 ~]# authconfig --disablecache --enablewinbind --enablewinbindauth --smbsecurity=ads --smbworkgroup=HOME --smbrealm=HOME.DOMAIN.COM --enablewinbindusedefaultdomain --winbindtemplatehomedir=/home/HOME.ABO PU.COM/%U --winbindtemplateshell=/bin/bash --enablekrb5 --krb5realm=HOME.DOMAIN.COM --enablekrb5kdcdns --enablekrb5realmdns --enablelocauthorize --enablemkhomedir --enablepamaccess --updateall
Job for winbind.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status winbind.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
[root@centos5 ~]#
```

And, I get the following in journalctl:

```
Mar 05 10:47:54 centos5.home.domain.com yum[22762]: Updated: krb5-libs-1.13.2-10.el7.x86_64
Mar 05 10:47:55 centos5.home.domain.com yum[22762]: Installed: pam_krb5-2.4.8-4.el7.x86_64
Mar 05 10:47:57 centos5.home.domain.com yum[22762]: Installed: krb5-workstation-1.13.2-10.el7.x86_64
Mar 05 10:47:58 centos5.home.domain.com yum[22762]: Updated: authconfig-6.2.8-10.el7.x86_64
Mar 05 10:48:13 centos5.home.domain.com polkitd[856]: Registered Authentication Agent for unix-process:22831:15953076 (system bus name :1.116 [/usr/bin/pkttyagent --notify-fd 47 --fallback], object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US.UTF-8)
Mar 05 10:48:13 centos5.home.domain.com systemd[1]: Reloading.
Mar 05 10:48:13 centos5.home.domain.com systemd[1]: Configuration file /usr/lib/systemd/system/auditd.service is marked world-inaccessible. This has no effect as configuration data is accessible via APIs without restrictions. Proceeding anyway.
Mar 05 10:48:13 centos5.home.domain.com systemd[1]: Configuration file /usr/lib/systemd/system/ebtables.service is marked executable. Please remove executable permission bits. Proceeding anyway.
Mar 05 10:48:13 centos5.home.domain.com polkitd[856]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-process:22831:15953076 (system bus name :1.116, object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US.UTF-8) (disconnected from bus)
Mar 05 10:48:14 centos5.home.domain.com polkitd[856]: Registered Authentication Agent for unix-process:22849:15953158 (system bus name :1.117 [/usr/bin/pkttyagent --notify-fd 47 --fallback], object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US.UTF-8)
Mar 05 10:48:14 centos5.home.domain.com systemd[1]: Stopped Samba Winbind Daemon.
Mar 05 10:48:14 centos5.home.domain.com polkitd[856]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-process:22849:15953158 (system bus name :1.117, object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US.UTF-8) (disconnected from bus)
Mar 05 10:48:14 centos5.home.domain.com polkitd[856]: Registered Authentication Agent for unix-process:22854:15953171 (system bus name :1.118 [/usr/bin/pkttyagent --notify-fd 47 --fallback], object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US.UTF-8)
Mar 05 10:48:15 centos5.home.domain.com systemd[1]: Starting Samba Winbind Daemon...
Mar 05 10:48:16 centos5.home.domain.com winbindd[22861]: [2016/03/05 10:48:16.221209,  0] ../source3/winbindd/winbindd_cache.c:3235(initialize_winbindd_cache)
Mar 05 10:48:16 centos5.home.domain.com winbindd[22861]:   initialize_winbindd_cache: clearing cache and re-creating with version number 2
Mar 05 10:48:16 centos5.home.domain.com winbindd[22861]: [2016/03/05 10:48:16.564406,  0] ../source3/winbindd/winbindd_util.c:736(init_domain_list)
Mar 05 10:48:16 centos5.home.domain.com winbindd[22861]:   Could not fetch our SID - did we join?
Mar 05 10:48:16 centos5.home.domain.com winbindd[22861]: [2016/03/05 10:48:16.564586,  0] ../source3/winbindd/winbindd.c:1294(winbindd_register_handlers)
Mar 05 10:48:16 centos5.home.domain.com winbindd[22861]:   unable to initialize domain list
Mar 05 10:48:16 centos5.home.domain.com systemd[1]: winbind.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Mar 05 10:48:16 centos5.home.domain.com systemd[1]: Failed to start Samba Winbind Daemon.
Mar 05 10:48:16 centos5.home.domain.com systemd[1]: Unit winbind.service entered failed state.
Mar 05 10:48:16 centos5.home.domain.com systemd[1]: winbind.service failed.
Mar 05 10:48:16 centos5.home.domain.com polkitd[856]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-process:22854:15953171 (system bus name :1.118, object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US.UTF-8) (disconnected from bus)
Mar 05 10:48:16 centos5.home.domain.com polkitd[856]: Registered Authentication Agent for unix-process:22864:15953418 (system bus name :1.119 [/usr/bin/pkttyagent --notify-fd 47 --fallback], object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US.UTF-8)
Mar 05 10:48:16 centos5.home.domain.com systemd[1]: Reloading.
Mar 05 10:48:16 centos5.home.domain.com systemd[1]: Configuration file /usr/lib/systemd/system/auditd.service is marked world-inaccessible. This has no effect as configuration data is accessible via APIs without restrictions. Proceeding anyway.
Mar 05 10:48:16 centos5.home.domain.com systemd[1]: Configuration file /usr/lib/systemd/system/ebtables.service is marked executable. Please remove executable permission bits. Proceeding anyway.
Mar 05 10:48:16 centos5.home.domain.com polkitd[856]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-process:22864:15953418 (system bus name :1.119, object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US.UTF-8) (disconnected from bus)
Mar 05 10:48:17 centos5.home.domain.com polkitd[856]: Registered Authentication Agent for unix-process:22882:15953455 (system bus name :1.120 [/usr/bin/pkttyagent --notify-fd 47 --fallback], object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US.UTF-8)
Mar 05 10:48:17 centos5.home.domain.com systemd[1]: Stopped privileged operations for unprivileged applications.
Mar 05 10:48:17 centos5.home.domain.com polkitd[856]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-process:22882:15953455 (system bus name :1.120, object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US.UTF-8) (disconnected from bus)
Mar 05 10:48:17 centos5.home.domain.com polkitd[856]: Registered Authentication Agent for unix-process:22887:15953465 (system bus name :1.121 [/usr/bin/pkttyagent --notify-fd 47 --fallback], object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US.UTF-8)
Mar 05 10:48:17 centos5.home.domain.com systemd[1]: Started privileged operations for unprivileged applications.
Mar 05 10:48:17 centos5.home.domain.com systemd[1]: Starting privileged operations for unprivileged applications...
Mar 05 10:48:17 centos5.home.domain.com polkitd[856]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-process:22887:15953465 (system bus name :1.121, object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US.UTF-8) (disconnected from bus)
Mar 05 10:48:17 centos5.home.domain.com polkitd[856]: Registered Authentication Agent for unix-process:22901:15953526 (system bus name :1.123 [/usr/bin/pkttyagent --notify-fd 47 --fallback], object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US.UTF-8)
Mar 05 10:48:17 centos5.home.domain.com systemd[1]: Stopped System Security Services Daemon.
Mar 05 10:48:17 centos5.home.domain.com polkitd[856]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-process:22901:15953526 (system bus name :1.123, object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US.UTF-8) (disconnected from bus)
Mar 05 10:48:17 centos5.home.domain.com polkitd[856]: Registered Authentication Agent for unix-process:22907:15953544 (system bus name :1.124 [/usr/bin/pkttyagent --notify-fd 47 --fallback], object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US.UTF-8)
Mar 05 10:48:17 centos5.home.domain.com systemd[1]: Reloading.
Mar 05 10:48:18 centos5.home.domain.com systemd[1]: Configuration file /usr/lib/systemd/system/auditd.service is marked world-inaccessible. This has no effect as configuration data is accessible via APIs without restrictions. Proceeding anyway.
Mar 05 10:48:18 centos5.home.domain.com systemd[1]: Configuration file /usr/lib/systemd/system/ebtables.service is marked executable. Please remove executable permission bits. Proceeding anyway.
Mar 05 10:48:18 centos5.home.domain.com polkitd[856]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-process:22907:15953544 (system bus name :1.124, object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US.UTF-8) (disconnected from bus)
Mar 05 10:48:18 centos5.home.domain.com polkitd[856]: Registered Authentication Agent for unix-process:22925:15953582 (system bus name :1.125 [/usr/bin/pkttyagent --notify-fd 47 --fallback], object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US.UTF-8)
Mar 05 10:48:18 centos5.home.domain.com polkitd[856]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-process:22925:15953582 (system bus name :1.125, object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US.UTF-8) (disconnected from bus)
```

What might be causing this?

Comment: Congratulations. The only other mention of this problem _anywhere_ is your copy of these logs on pastebin. You've truly got an odd one here. I would suggest filing a bug report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this issue and (after hours of investigations) was able to resolve it by upgrading my packages using yum. i.e.

`yum upgrade`

Comment: This looks like it may be the solution. I'll have to confirm for sure though!

Answer (score 0):

Agent 154.

I believe you have to previously create the machine account (computer account) in an AD container whithin which the user has full access to (that is the user provided to the command "realm join").

Hope it helps.